# Access $amount in Factory possible?

Tags: laravel

Is it somehow possible to get the $amount specified in the factory(SomeClass::class, 30) helper, from inside the factory closure?

I need to reset a helper method every xy iterations, and would love if I can simply access that number somehow.... :)

ie:

```
$factory->define(......, function(Faker $faker) {
 $amount = $factory->amount; // 30
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$factory->define(......, function(Faker $faker)use($factory) {
 $amount = $factory->amount; // 30
}
```

Comment: lol :) Thanks, but that was just my pseudo code example, sadly that doesn't work